# AuditLogView in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

In developing AuditLogView in Java, I am trying to get filtered by "Object:www.test.com". How can I add a filter Object below?

```
    com.softlayer.api.service.event.Log.Service eventLogService =
```

com.softlayer.api.service.event.Log.service(client);

```
    eventLogService.setResultLimit(new ResultLimit(0,50));
    Filter filter = new Filter();
    filter.addFilter("label").addProperty("name","???");
    eventLogService.addFilter(filter);

    List<Log> a = eventLogService.getAllObjects();
```

Answer (score 0):

The SoftLayer API Client for Java does not support object filters yet, there is an issue opened for this: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java/issues/30

You need to filter the result in your code or use another programming language.
You can see the programming languages supported by SoftLayer in the following link:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/